# How to simply the if/else condition codes

Tags: jquery

I am trying to simplfy the following script. The conditional statement seems to redundant Are there anyone here helping me out? Thanks a lot.

```
function createHelpImage(element, elementType){

  $element = $(element);
  if(elementType=='img'){

    $(document.createElement('img'))
    .attr({src:'inc/images/help_bubble.png', title:'help Image', 'class': 'helpImg'})
    .insertBefore($element)
    .css({'position':'absolute',
      'z-index':999
    })
    .position({
      my: 'left bottom',
      at: 'left center',
      of: $element

    });
  }else{
    $(document.createElement('img'))
    .attr({src:'inc/images/help_bubble.png', title:'help Image', 'class': 'helpImg'})
    .prependTo($element)
    .css({'position':'absolute',
      'z-index':999
    })
    .position({
      my: 'left bottom',
      at: 'left center',
      of: $element[0]

    });
  }
}
```

Comment: -1 Well, what have you done/come up with? **The first part of simplification/unification is to identify what is common, and what isn't.** (Please, start by identifying this ..)

Answer (score 2):

Try using the [ternary operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/?%3a#JavaScript) on the last line:

```
 of: (elementType=='img') ? $elemen : $elemen[0]
```

This is assuming that only the last line is different in your if/else code blocks.  Your code would look like this:

```
function createHelpImage(element, elementType){
    $(document.createElement('img'))
    .attr({src:'inc/images/help_bubble.png', title:'help Image', 'class': 'helpImg'})
    .insertBefore($element)
    .css({'position':'absolute',
      'z-index':999
    })
    .position({
      my: 'left bottom',
      at: 'left center',
      of: (elementType=='img') ? $element : $element[0]
    });  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just remove the redundant code from the if/else, use a variable to hold the value for `of` then set it after

```
$element = $(element);
var of;
var img = $(document.createElement('img'))
    .attr({src:'inc/images/help_bubble.png', title:'help Image', 'class': 'helpImg'})       
    .css({'position':'absolute',
       'z-index':999
    })
if(elementType=='img'){
    img.insertBefore($element);
            of = $element;
}
else{
    img.prependTo($element);
            of = $element[0];
}
img.position({
    my: 'left bottom',
    at: 'left center',
    of: of
});
```

Comment: You missed the other difference :) prependTo/insertBefore. But you're still right, it's the DRY principle.

Answer (score 0):

Just take the differences and put the if statement around those. There is a principle called Don't Repeat Yourself (DRY for short) which applies here.